# Somebody's wife got pregnant

Tags: idioms

Jane got pregnant from Tom. I mean Tom will be a father. I am not sure if "from" is a proper word in that case.

And the second problem. Tom got to know that he would get to be a father. Or would become a father. Any common expressions or idioms for that?

Comment: It's very trendy now to say "Tom and Jane are pregnant". I think this is  unfairly elevating Tom's stance in the situation moving forward. "Tom and Jane are expecting" is a polite way of saying that Jane is pregnant, while implicating Tom in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Jane got pregnant from Tom. I mean Tom will be a father. I am not sure
>   if "from" is a proper word in that case.

No it isn't; the proper form would be: *Jane got pregnant **by** Tom*.

Examples of usage:

> Teacher turns herself in after allegedly getting pregnant by 13-year-old.
>   http://nypost.com/2017/01/13/teacher-who-got-pregnant-by-13-year-old-student-gets-10-years-in-jail/
>
> "PREGNANT BY YOUR HUSBAND'S BOYFRIEND"
>   [https://www.amazon.com/PREGNANT-YOUR-HUSBANDS-BOYFRIEND-LINETTE-ebook/dp/B01IAYKG2Y/ref=sr_1_6?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1484736530&sr=1-6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IAYKG2Y)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for an idiom:

> Jane and Tom are expecting a ***visit from the stork***.

TFD (idioms):

> **[visit from the stork](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/visit+from+the+stork)**
>
> *Fig*. a birth. (According to legend, babies are brought to their parents by a stork.) 
>   I hear that Maria is expecting a visit from the
>   stork.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.