# “Who are you pregnant by?” or “By whom are you pregnant?”

Tags: grammar, phrase-request

> “Who are you pregnant by?” or
>   “By whom are you pregnant?”

What is the best way of asking about the father of the child?

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about the difference between using "by whom" and "who... by" and paternity happens to be the example? Or do you really want ask about paternity in a natural way and these are your examples? Please try to include those kinds of details in your posts.

Comment: Related question: [Somebody's wife got pregnant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/116090/9161)

Comment: @Em. I think that initially, my question was about the difference between _by whom_ and _who... by_ but other useful facts are very important anyway.

Comment: @Aer Sorry, I should have been clearer. I asked because your question was flagged as "unclear" and I am guessing that was the concern. The focus and goal of the question should be clear.  So make sure to include more details, like the goal of your question, what you know, and other relevant information. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, the “by whom” example is the so-called correct, formal one. However, the “who” example is the usual way people speak.

However, asking about paternity is a very touchy subject. You could easily offend the mother by asking this. In particular, your examples seem rather crude to me. If you think it is safe to talk about it, I think there are more idiomatic ways to ask. For example

> Who is the father?
>   Who's the dad/daddy? (Casual)

If you insist on using a verb related to “pregnancy”, you could use *impregnate*

> Who impregnated you?
>
> - [impregnate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impregnate)
>     2 Make (a woman or female animal) pregnant.
>     *‘he was obliged to marry the woman he'd impregnated’*
>     (ODO)

This is sounds rather forward and formal.

Comment: Possibly rude to enquire about the  paternity in any manner, unless you know the person really well or are a close relative.

Comment: I would say "impregnate" sounds clinical - like a doctor might ask a patient. Actually, a situation where there is a medical or legal reason to ask might be the only situation where asking a woman who the father of her unborn child is appropriate.

Comment: I'd say _who_ _knocked_ _you_ _up_? but it could be rude or amusing depending on how you say it, and who you say it to.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences do not sound good or natural English to me. "Who got you pregnant?" would sound more natural English.